# Where is eax in the pt_regs struct? Only ax is present

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel, kernel

I am trying to use the `pt_regs` struct to get and set registers such as `eax`, but compilation errors tell me that `pt_regs` has no such member `eax`.

However, I am able to get the `ax` register. Can anybody tell me what is happening?

I am using 32-bit Ubuntu linux with the `3.0.0` kernel. Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the definition of `struct pt_regs` in [arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.0/source/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h).

Notice `#ifndef __KERNEL__` stuff there, it means that the definition of that structure is different for kernel-mode and user-mode code.

For the kernel code, `pt_regs::ax` is probably the value you need. It should contain the value of `%eax` on a 32-bit system and `%rax` on a 64-bit one.

Comment: You're right in your last comment. See [head_64.S](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/kernel/head_64.S#L358). Of course, there is also a 32 bit version with a similar name.