# Get userspace RBP register from kernel syscall

Tags: c, linux-kernel, x86, kernel-module, cpu-registers

I am writing a kernel system call and I want to read the base pointer register (RBP) of the user. Maybe I can do that using the `pt_regs` struct that is passed for parameter, isn't it?

Example code:

```
unsigned long int data;
asmlinkage int my_read(int d)
{
    get_rbp_of_userStack(&data);#or somthing like that 

}
```

I know this data saved somewhere for the context switch, how can I get to it?

this is my user code

```
 void rar()
{//rbp here should be rsp when it call so it basically the return addres of the main
  char t[10];
getchar();
 }
 
int main()
{
  rar();
}
```

Comment: You're looking for `bp` in the `struct pt_regs` for the current task.  [Where is eax in the pt\_regs struct? Only ax is present](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10070625)

Comment: @PeterCordes but how can I load the new pt_regs so it wont be null ?

Comment: IIRC, `current` (of tyep task_struct) has a pt_regs member.  But I don't do a lot of kernel code stuff so I didn't post an answer.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks a lot for your answer :-)

Comment: *rbp here should be rsp when it call so it basically the return addres of the main* - uh, what?  If you compile with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` then RBP points at a saved RBP, yes.  But libc wrappers for system calls are not usually compiled that way, so unless you inline the `syscall` with an `asm()` statement, that probably won't be the case.  And saved-RBP values aren't return addresses; they're traditionally *next* to return addresses.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I know it just an example usually it point the return in the stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`task_pt_regs()`](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.8/source/arch/x86/include/asm/processor.h#L843) macro to get the `current` task's user registers (saved at the moment of syscall entry):

```c
#include <asm/processor.h>

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(foo, int, d)
{
    const struct pt_regs *user_regs = task_pt_regs(current);
    unsigned long rbp = user_regs->bp;

    /* Do whatever you need... */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: for some reason I am getting the same values so I think that something is incorrect

Comment: @AlonShoam Well, you'll have to provide a [mre] of both the userspace program and the module then... otherwise it's impossible to help. Also, what's your kernel version?

Comment: I am using kernel 4.15 and I add the code to the question

Comment: @AlonShoam your userspace code is not making any syscall. It's not a reproducible example. Also, you should tell us the two RBP values you get, and how do you get them.

Comment: sorry I add now an example but any way I know it call the syscall buecase I printed it pid in the system call and value I get is 00000000f01fbc03 I also open  another thread becuase the two case not really relaited