# Trying to read register values of a process from task_struct

Tags: c, assembly, linux-kernel, driver, cpu-registers

Currently I'm able to find the register values for the program which was written, but not for other processes.

What I have written so far is is:

```
#include <linux/sched.h>


struct task_struct *task_list;

for_each_process(task_list){
        register int* pc asm("%pc");
        register int mar asm("%mar");
        register int mdr asm("%mdr");
        register int cir asm("%cir");
        register int acc asm("%acc");
        register int ir asm("%ir");
        register int eax asm("%eax");
        register int ebx asm("%ebx");
        register int ecx asm("%ecx");
        register int edx asm("%edx");
        register int ip asm("%ip");
        register int esp asm("%esp");
        register int ebp asm("%ebp");
        register int esi asm("%esi");
        register int edi asm("%edi");
        register int of asm("%of");
        register int df asm("%df");
        register int _if asm("%if");
        register int tf asm("%tf");
        register int sf asm("%sf");
        register int zf asm("%zf");
        register int af asm("%af");
        register int pf asm("%pf");
        register int cf asm("%cf");
}
```

I realize I need to use task_list and point to an element within the struct [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/kernel/sched/sched.h), but I cannot seem to locate which element contains the registers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the registers from a `task_struct` using the macro `task_pt_regs()`.  It yields a pointer to a `struct pt_regs` ([definition](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/f6e1ea19649216156576aeafa784e3b4cee45549/arch/x86/include/asm/ptrace.h#L12)) which is the saved copy of all the thread's registers from when it entered the kernel.

For example:

```
    struct task_struct *t = /* find the one you want */ ;
    unsigned long tasks_eax = task_pt_regs(t)->ax;
```

Note despite the name, the `ax` member is the full 32-bit `eax` register (on x86-32) or 64-bit `rax` register (on x86-64).

See also:

- [Get userspace RBP register from kernel syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64577963/get-userspace-rbp-register-from-kernel-syscall)
- [Where is eax in the pt_regs struct? Only ax is present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070625/where-is-eax-in-the-pt-regs-struct-only-ax-is-present?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: How do I get access to the program counter? I get an error.

Comment: @roger: `task_pt_regs(t)->ip`?  The program counter register on x86 is named `ip / eip / rip`.